# Manually Running Specific Method Within Viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I looked around a bit on how to manually trigger a Viewmodel to run again, but wasn't sure they were directed towards what I actually want.

What I want to do is be able to run a specific Method that is inside of my Viewmodel whenever a specific Window is closed, without running all of them. Is there a way that I could bind this Method to the Closed Event of the second Window? Thanks.

Comment: So your second window also has a viewmodel, right? So you have viewmodel for each window?

Comment: I do not. I only have one for my main window, but would like for a specific method that is within that Viewmodel to trigger whenever I close the second one, so that the changes to my Database that were made within the second window reflect back on the main window.

Comment: And where do you create that window? Do you create it inside viewmodel? Do you have a reference to that window? In order to really get what mvvm has to offer I would just create a viewmodel for the second window and then bind it to the event. Otherwise you are left with code behind and events

Comment: I do not have any of that. I'll probably have to do what you said and create another Viewmodel and tie it to the Closed event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stick to `MVVM` and do it properly, in a easy to extend and maintain way you can do this like this:

```
public class FirstViewModel : IWindowCloseNotifier {

   public SecondViewModel SecondVm { get; set; }

    public FirstViewModel() 
    {
      SecondVm = new SecondViewModel(this);  
    }

    public void Close(IWindowCloseNotifierArgs args)
    {
       // Window is now closed!
    }
}
```

Interface ensures that `SecondViewModel` can use only `Close` method.

```
 public interface IWindowCloseNotifier {
        void Close(IWindowClosedArgs args);
    }

    public class SecondViewModel {

        private readonly IWindowCloseNotifier _windowCloseNotifier;

        public SecondViewModel(IWindowCloseNotifier windowCloseNotifier) {
          _windowCloseNotifier = windowCloseNotifier;
        }

        public void OnClose()
        {
           _windowCloser.Close(your args);
        }
    }
```

If your `SecondViewModel` is not a child of `FirstViewModel` then use Publish Subscribe Pattern to communicate between viewmodels.

My naming is not great, but I don't have any other ideas.

Answer (score 0):

are you using MVVM Light or any other MVVM framework ?

if so: you have multiple options depending on your design you might want to choose

1. EventToCommand
2. Messenger(If i go this route create a Behavior and keep logic there , so its clean)